# Haskell -- how to use the new 4-argument quasi quoter

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

It looks like the quasi quoter syntax has changed to now accept 4 arguments [ [link](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/libraries/template-haskell-2.5.0.0/Language-Haskell-TH-Quote.html) ]. Has anyone used it yet? Thanks. I just want to build something really really simple, and the examples on the web won't work now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you just set the new one to `undefined`? (Not sure if that works, very little experience with quasis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each piece of the `QuasiQuoter` is just a function that takes a string (the content of the quasi-quote) and returns an appropriate value in the `Q` monad. If your quasiquoter doesn't support being used in some of those contexts, just return an error, e.g.:

```
someQuoter = QuasiQuoter { quoteType = const $ fail "type context unsupported" 
                         , -- etc ...
                         }
```

The `fail` method calls `report True`, which produces a compiler error. This is pretty much the correct behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the changes are that you can now make quasiquoters for types and declarations (in addition to expressions and patterns).

It should be fine to set the type/declaration fields to `error "This quasiquoter doesn't support splicing types/declarations"` if you don't want to use them.